# max_pool_size not available in pg_bouncer.ini

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

The docs describe something about the max_pool_size at:
https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html

However neither my nore for example the default pgbouncer.ini have a config parameter "max_pool_size", only the "default_pool_size":
https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/blob/master/etc/pgbouncer.ini

That just seems confusing?
Is default_pool_size == max_pool_size or what shall that mean ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `max_pool_size` is not a parameter - [it is used in formula](https://pgbouncer.github.io/config.html):

> max_client_conn + (max_pool_size * total_databases * total_users)

also:

> ## default_pool_size
>
> How many server connections to **allow per user/database pair**. Can be overridden in the per-database
>   configuration.
>
> Default: 20

Emphasis mine.

So here max_pool_size is default_pool_size. Eg for default 20, It would mean that you should increase file descriptor limits to at least 100+(20*1*1) = 120 for default max_client_conn, default default_pool_size, one database and one user.

### Update

[The most precise meaning](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/190#issuecomment-285691061):

> max_pool_size is max(pool_size, default_pool_size)